# Flatten multiple columns into new rows

Tags: excel

How can I turn a table with duplicated columns:

```
ID    Var     Var     Name     Name
01    0001    0002    Bill     Jim
02    0003    0004    Sam      Kyle
```

into a new table where each original column only appears once, and its values are split among new rows with duplicated independent variables.

```
ID    Var     Name
01    0001    Bill
01    0002    Jim
02    0003    Sam
02    0004    Kyle
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try in this way as well,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A7` for the ID's

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$3,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/2)+1)
```

---

• Formula used in cell `B7` for Var's

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$3,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$3,0),MOD((ROW(A1)-1),2)+1)
```

---

• Formula used in cell `C7` for Name's

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$3,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$3,0),MOD((ROW(A1)-1),2)+3)
```

---

Edit,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `A7`

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$3,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/MAX(COUNTIF($B$1:$I$1,$B$1:$I$1))+1))
```

• Formula used in cell `B7`

```
=INDEX($B$2:$I$3,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$3,0),
MOD((ROW(A1)-1),MAX(COUNTIF($B$1:$I$1,$B$1:$I$1)))+MATCH(B$6,$B$1:$I$1,0))
```

And Fill down & Fill Right !

---

Alternatively we can use this as well,

For ID in cell `A7`

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$3,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/(COLUMNS($B$1:$I$1)/2)+1))
```

in cell `B7`

```
=INDEX($B$2:$I$3,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$3,0),
MOD((ROW(A1)-1),COLUMNS($B$1:$I$1)/2)+MATCH(B$6,$B$1:$I$1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Are the numbers based on the number of duplicated columns? What if there were 4 Names and Vars instead of 2?

Comment: Yes, for that we can use `MATCH(B$6,$B$1:$E$1,0)` instead of 1 while for 3 we can use `MATCH(C$6,$B$1:$E$1,0)`

Comment: Whaat do the `$` dollar signs do?

Comment: Dollar Signs `$` are anchors, so we taking the absolute ranges here, so when we drag the references dont change. Refer answers I have updated the formulas,

Comment: @minseong does that help to resolve?

Comment: The value the second formula reports the first time is from the third set of columns, not the first. For more than two sets of duplicated columns do more numbers need to change?

Comment: Is your data, going to update every time, or how may columns are there in total? Also may i know what version of Excel you are using

Comment: Excel 16.53 and the number of columns in total is 10 unique titles (4 each).

Comment: That last formula should work, only you need to increase the range

Comment: Even still COLUMNS/2 ?

Comment: Yes Sir, this part, `COLUMNS($B$1:$I$1)/2)+MATCH(B$6,$B$1:$I$1,0)` is significant, if your data has increased then change the range i.e. extend it